# Integration Roxy Fileman in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, integration

I'm trying to integrate the Roxy Fileman (http://www.roxyfileman.com) in TinyMCE.

Unable to make the icon appear Roxy Fileman after clicking Trigger Image of TinyMCE but it is not working correctly.

When I open the Roxy Fileman received from these mistakes obvious warning from Chrome:

E_LoadingConf 
E_ActionDisabled 
Error loading language file

I have already sent a message to the staff of the Roxy Fileman but got no answer.

Can anyone help me integrate this? I need a way to upload photos on TinyMCE.

If anyone has any other plugin to indicate I accept.

Below is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
// This must be set to the absolute path from the site root.
var roxyFileman = 'js/tinymce/plugins/fileman/index.html?integration=tinymce4';
$(function() {
tinyMCE.init({language : 'pt_BR', selector: 'textarea#elm1', menubar : false, plugins: 'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality template paste textcolor', 
             toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | link image | bullist numlist outdent indent | forecolor", file_browser_callback: RoxyFileBrowser});
});
function RoxyFileBrowser(field_name, url, type, win) {
var cmsURL = roxyFileman;  // script URL - use an absolute path!
if (cmsURL.indexOf("?") < 0) {
cmsURL = cmsURL + "?type=" + type;
}
else {
cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=" + type;
}
cmsURL += '&input=' + field_name + '&value=' + document.getElementById(field_name).value;
tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
file: cmsURL,
title: 'Upload de Arquivos',
width: 850, // Your dimensions may differ - toy around with them!
height: 650,
resizable: "yes",
plugins: "media",
inline: "yes", // This parameter only has an effect if you use the inlinepopups plugin!
close_previous: "no"
}, {
window: win,
input: field_name
  });
return false;
}
</script>
```

*TinyMCE is 4.0.16 (2014-01-31). Roxy'm running on Windows server with support for PHP 5.2.17.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried changing the conf.json file
the integration should be changed from custom to :-

```
"INTEGRATION":         "tinymce4",
```

And possibly in your web config adding

```
<system.webServer>
 ...
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>
...
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that Roxy Fileman configuration and language files are misssing or contain syntax errors. 
Try to load js/tinymce/plugins/fileman/conf.json in your browser and see the result. All configuration and language files are in json format and must be utf8 encoded.

You can also debug using developer tools -> network to see the server responses when Fileman initializes.

E_LoadingConf means that configuration file cannot be loaded or parsed.
E_ActionDisabled is because the configuration is not loaded

Comment: My conf.json came up a parser error as I'd put a drive letter in there.  That cured the "E_LoadingConf" error.  Now however I getting a  "There are no files to upload or the file is too big" error once I pick the file.

Comment: Thats right, I´d the same problem and was a json sintax error. Use: http://pro.jsonlint.com/ to validate

Answer (score 3):

`E_LoadingConf` and `E_ActionDisabled` Error loading language file are errors that might be caused because your server is not configured to handle json files properly.

You will need to configure json as a new mime type.

If your server works with IIS, you need to follow the steps listed on [this page](http://www.uipress.com/add-json-handler-support-in-iis-7/#.U_SqlWP7CXI)

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Try changes this

> document.getElementById(field_name)

To be

> document.getElementById("your_id_tinymce")

Comment: Can you explain the difference please?

Comment: due to variable "field_name" is not defined, and it'll generates an error